# SP2010 SP1 release date?

Tags: 2010

Any news on when SP1 for SharePoint 2010 will be out? specifically interested in Framework 4.0 compatibility.

Given the comments below, I should clarify the Framework 4.0 Compatibility - namely not that SP2010 will run on 4.0 but that the Object Model can be called from 4.0 apps on the same server. At the moment calls to the OM from a 4.0 App returns an error stating that you are using an unsupported version of the framework.  Will that type of use be supported? is there a site/blog I should be following to find out what will be added/changed in SP1?

Comment: Do you think it will support NetFx4?

Comment: I doubt that .NET Fx4 will be supported in the upcoming Service Pack...

Comment: Since that would be a major breaking change, I'm willing to bet my firstborn child that SharePoint 2010 will stay on 3.5SP1 forever and only the successor product will support a newer Framework :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service Pack 1 for SharePoint 2010 is scheduled for a release in June 2010.

The SharePoint Team blog contains all the details you need: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=973

Also read the Office Sustained Engineering blog post about the SP1 announcement: http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-service-pack-1-for-office-2010-and-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This has now been released as of June 28, 2011.  The details are in the blog post here:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=984